# how to kill a process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've launched wampserver using vb.net when the application loads. My problem is, how do I kill the wamp server process when I exit the program.

Comment: Look at the methods available on the `Process` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim arrProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("wampserver")

For Each p As Process In arrProcess
   p.Kill()
Next
```

Comment: the same as here:http://vbnetsample.blogspot.com/2007/08/start-and-kill-process.html
it doesnt work for me: "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"

Comment: the code, the process still sits at the taskbar after having hit the button that executes the code. I even put the directory to which the executable file is located but still won't work.

Comment: oops, sorry. it works, the only problem is the taskbar, thanks

Comment: Glad you where able to figure out the problem - Cheers