# close command window from windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, node.js

I have a simple Node.js program which execute through a button click from winform, that works fine, But i need to terminate the Node.js program and close the command prompt on another button click.How can i achieve this?

Cheers
Jeev

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: to start a process i have used      Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe")    I am sure the close function will be something like this, but have no idea how to implement :(

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426573/how-do-you-kill-a-process-for-a-particular-user-in-net-c

Comment: And also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642231/how-to-kill-a-c-sharp-process?rq=1

Comment: I tried with  Dim ps As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe")      For Each p As Process In ps
            p.Kill()
        Next       But it's showing the error"Couldnt connect to remote machine"

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308249/how-to-kill-a-process-in-vb-net?rq=1

Comment: Still getting the same error.Can u tel me what parameter should i pass within GetProcessesByName ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21801/discussion-between-mamta-dalal-and-jeev1989)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If YOU start the process, you have an object of type `process`. This object supports `kill` which will end the process immediately.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
Public Class Form1

Dim MyProcess As Process

Private Sub btnStartPrcoess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartPrcoess.Click

    If MyProcess Is Nothing Then
        MyProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "arguments")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnKillProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnKillProcess.Click

    If MyProcess IsNot Nothing Then
        MyProcess.Kill()
        MyProcess.Close()
        MyProcess = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

If you need to end the process from a different method, you need to declare the process-variable on class level of course. And even `Process.Start()` has a return value of type process. So there is no need to SEARCH for the process - you already know it!

**UPDATE**

It's more or less nonsense, to do something like this:

```
MyProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k notepad.exe")
```

Because it simply starts the cmd.exe which then starts notepad.exe. And of course the `Process` now "points" to cmd.exe and not to notepad.exe. If you want to have notepad running, it's obviously the best solution to start it DIRECTLY:

```
MyProcess = Process.Start("notepad.exe", "arguments for notepad, if needed")
```

Comment: Actually on 1 button click the process is started and now on another button click it should be killed.I tried with    for close button                                 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click    Dim ps As Process() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("exit.exe")  For Each p As Process In ps
            p.Kill()
        Next  End Sub

Comment: how do i specify the process name?? is it  "cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe" or just exit.exe ??

Comment: Again: there is no need to SEARCH the process! You already have everything you need!

Comment: well that worked when a command window is just opened and the close button is clicked, whereas if i execute my node prog and then try the close button it wont close. is there anything else i need to include with this?

Comment: Maybe the question is, why you start cmd.exe and not the .exe you REALLY want to run?

Comment: How do i execute a .exe file directly? i used  MyProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe")

Comment: MyProcess = Process.Start("C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe")

Answer (score 2):

You have used `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe")` to start the process. So declare a global `Process` varible and try;

```
Process exeProcess;
```

on start button click:

```
 exeProcess = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\exit.exe");
```

On stop button click;

```
exeProcess.Kill();
```